# java check if Skypename exists

Tags: java, skype

I have a Java Web application, and I have a registration form for users. And I wanna check if skypename is real or not.
Is there Skype API, which helps to know whether skypename exists or not? :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such API available. The only way to verify a Skype name is to attempt to add the given name as a contact. (Which you obviously wouldn't want to do in a registration form).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a Skype Java API. [Skype4Java](http://skype.sourceforge.jp/index.php?Skype%20API%20For%20Java%20%28English%29) is one of those. However, I'm not sure if it is still actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

API I havn't found. But there is a good thread: [Skype username validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951625/skype-username-validation) It seeems, that it can helps in some situations.