# Skype username validation - No Access control allow origin header is present

Tags: angularjs, http, cross-domain, skype

I'm just following another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951625/skype-username-validation) to perform the skype user name validation. When i perform the HTTP POST

POST https://login.skype.com/json/validator

data params : new_username='XXX'

using `Postman` chrome plugin, I'm getting the below valid response to it. so, i think this API method is allowed to be performed

```
{
  "status": 406,
  "status_text": "valid",
  "data": {
    "markup": "Skype Name not available",
    "alternatives": true,
    "fieldDetails": "<label>Suggestions</label><ul><li><label><input class=\"skypeNameSuggestion\" type=\"radio\" name=\"selectSkypeName\" value=\"keerthivasan.ramanathan1\"/>keerthivasan.ramanathan1</label></li></ul>"
  }
}
```

But, when i perform the same stuff in angular js service, i get the below error. Can someone explain the behind scenes nuances involved? I'm sure the preflight response fails. How can i make it pass? How does it work properly with Postman app in chrome?  I have also made configuration changes to http headers in angular

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','$httpProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

**ERROR**
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.skype.com/json/validator. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Can someone help me understand? Also, if someone knows a better option to findout, if a skype name is valid using angular js. Please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the service you're calling doesn't accept cross domain requests. This isn't a problem in Postman because Postman takes the information you give it and then builds and executes requests on the server side.

Since you're using AngularJS and Spring. Try creating a new endpoint in Spring that takes requests from Angular with body:{data params : new_username='XXX'} and POSTs that to https://login.skype.com/json/validator from the back end.

Comment: If you give me more information about the technology stack you're using I may be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm using angular js to perform this request. I'm using Spring mvc in the server side. How can cross domain request will be allowed, if i hit the request from the server side? that also runs in the localhost.Can you explain? i may be missing your words.

Comment: @Keerthivasan Happy to help. Cross origin access control is handled by the browser. It's based off of the protocol, domain name and port (plus some other factors) that your front end request is being made from. Server side requests are not handled by a browser and do not have the same information associated with them. Here's a good breakdown of how CORS requests work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked when i hit the request from my server side application.